# DjangoRest serializers: Save Foreignkey relation and serialize

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am new to Django rest and serializers concept

I have this kind of DB structure

User 1->N Address,
User 1->N Phone

`User` is a django.contrib.auth.models.User. `Address` and `Phone` both models contains this field `user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

In my UserSerializer looks like this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    address = AddressSerializer(many=False)
    phone = PhoneSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id', 'username',
            'first_name', 'last_name',
            'email', 'password',
            'address', 'phone')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Save user.
        user = User.objects.create(
                first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                username=validated_data['username'],
                email=validated_data['email'],
            )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        # User's address
        address_data = validated_data['address']
        address_data['user_id'] = user.id
        address = Address.objects.create(**address_data)
        # User's phone
        phone_data = validated_data['phone']
        phone_data['user_id'] = user.id
        phone = Phone.objects.create(**phone_data)
        return user
```

And AddressSerializer:

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = (
                'user_id', 'address', 'pin_code', 'state', 'city', 'country')
```

I am able to create `User` but while doing `serializer.data` I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `address` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'address'.
```

EDIT:

My `create` method looks like this

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    password = validated_data.pop('password')
    validated_data['username'] = validated_data['email']
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Are you not seeing notifications to my replies in comments to my answer?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I see the notification. Sorry, was not checking the browser.

Comment: Just checking thought maybe there was problem with notifications because you have unicode latters in your username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fields for address and phone should be called `address_set` and `phone_set` if you haven't specified `related_name` explicitly

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address_set = AddressSerializer(many=False)
    phone_set = PhoneSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id', 'username',
            'first_name', 'last_name',
            'email', 'password',
            'address_set', 'phone_set'
        )
```

or

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer(many=False, source='address_set')
    phone = PhoneSerializer(many=False, source='phone_set')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id', 'username',
            'first_name', 'last_name',
            'email', 'password',
            'address', 'phone'
        )
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Can you add an example to your answer?

Comment: I am getting error `AssertionError: The field 'phone' was declared on serializer UserSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.`

Comment: @De̲̳̳ath-Stalke̲̳̳r ah yes. fields should be called address_set too. See update

Comment: Umm... a new error `TypeError: 'address_set' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: @De̲̳̳ath-Stalke̲̳̳r add full trace of error to your post

Comment: You need to pop `address_set` and `phone_set` from `validated_data` before doing `user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)`

Comment: Ok. Please see the edit. Do I also need to save address and phone objects.create() separately in create?

Comment: @De̲̳̳ath-Stalke̲̳̳r yes.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I have one more question, how do I get the address and phone data when doing `serializer.data`.(One way is to override `to_represent` method but it seems hacky way)

Comment: @De̲̳̳ath-Stalke̲̳̳r it will be probably better to create separate question for this.